# TabBarView: Controller's length property (2) does not match the number of tabs (1) present in TabBar's tabs property

Tags: android, flutter, dart, tabbar

Getting the error as in the title. Of course this is a straightforward thing to check, but some weird behaviour happens. I'm creating a TabBarView with either 1 or 2 tabs, depending on argument in constructor (`numTabs`). Now Flutter asserts even when the length of tabs is clearly 2 - the controller length is determined by this value, but `widget.children.length` in `Tabs.dart` thinks it has a length of one.

Then more strange behaviour: when the length of the TabController is hardcoded as 1, then the two switch, I then get the error `Controller's length property (1) does not match the number of tabs (2) present in TabBar's tabs property`. So now it knows there are two tabs in TabBar.

Edit: It should be noted that it only happens when I pass in `numTabs` as 2. `numTabs = 1` works fine and as expected.

Any help will be appreciated. Here is the code (everything inside a stateful widget):

```
  List<Widget> tabs;
  List<Widget> tabViews ;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
     tabs = (widget.numTabs == 1) ? List(1) : List(2) ;
     tabViews = (widget.numTabs == 1) ? List(1) : List(2) ;
    _tabController = new TabController(vsync: this, length: tabs.length);
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  if (widget.numTabs == 1){
      tabs[0] = (new Tab(text: "Update"));
      tabViews[0] = (_someWidget1);
  }else{
    tabs = [new Tab(text: "Post 1"), new Tab(text: "Post 2")];
    tabViews[0] = (_someWidget1);
    tabViews[1] = (_someWidget2);
  }

  return TabBarView(
         controller: _tabController,
            children: <Widget>[ Scaffold(
                appBar: PreferredSize(
                  preferredSize:
                      Size.fromHeight(screenHeight(context, dividedBy: 5)),
                  child: AppBar(
                    flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                      title: Center(
                            Text('Title'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    bottom: TabBar(
                      controller: _tabController,
                      tabs: tabs,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                body: new TabBarView(
                  controller: _tabController,
                  children: tabViews,
                )),
             ],
          );
     }
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you find any solution?

Comment: Hi @RanaRanvijaySingh   No solution to the above problem. I ended up just checking for numTabs parameter, and then either building a Scaffold if it is one tab, or building a DefaultTabController if 2.

Answer (score 0):

This one is a simple problem you can fix it bye if condition
**if you can't fix this then you can upload your full file and I will try to fix**

```
if(items.length >= 3){
  return getBody(items);
}
else{
  return Container();
}
```